# How can I use additional type-faces with Android widgets?

Tags: android, basic4android

Is there any way of using additional type-faces in Android widgets?

```
Dim GothicFont As Typeface
GothicFont = Typeface.LoadFromAssets("gothic.ttf")
```

I just want to use Century Gothic font with a text label in my home screen widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to load a custom font file as the widget is hosted in a different process. Your only option is to use Canvas to draw the text.